# get mimeType of selected video or image in cordova getPicture

Tags: cordova

I am using `navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options)` to pick an image or video, but

```
fileEntry.getFormatData(function (metadata) {
    alert("mimeType = " + metadata.type);
}, function () {
    alert("fail");
});


alert(JSON.stringify(fileEntry.getMetadata()));
alert('to URL ' + fileEntry.toURL());
alert('name' + fileEntry.name)
```

None of the above code working!

The actual problem is when I pick a video from Photolibrary, it does not give extension, it gives path like `content://zxxxxx/123` when I am uploading it with fileTransfer plugin it is uploading with mimeType image/jpeg, what can I do for this? How can I fix this issue... So none of transcoding at server is working

Comment: Are you pick the image/video or shoot in camera.

Comment: @Aravin Picking it. If I record I am getting mimeType in that path itself

Comment: `fileEntry.file(gotFile, onFail);      function gotFile(file) {
 alert(file.type);
 alert(file.size);
 
}`

Comment: try the above........

Comment: @Aravin trying it, will let u know in 2 mins. Thanks

Comment: @Aravin Its undefined....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52744/discussion-between-redv-and-aravin)

Answer (score 0):

```
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var slice = file.slice(0,4);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function( e ) {
                console.log('in reader.load');
                onSuccess( fileEntry.toURL(), file.type );
            };
            reader.onerror = function( e ) {
                console.log('error trying to get file: ' + fileName);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer( slice );
        });
```

This way you only load first 4 bytes to detect the mimie type and avoid loading complete file to the memory